# Adding Strings to listbox from a background worker (invoking)

Tags: c#, string, winforms, listbox, backgroundworker

I'm fairly new to coding c# and am trying to use a background worker (to avoid stopping my GUI) to run a ping loop, the results of which will be printed to a listbox within my gui every ping much as a standard cmd prompt.

My code compiles but text does not appear in the listbox, any help as to where i'm going wrong would be great.

Thanks

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int secs = DateTime.Now.Second;
        while (keepgoing == true)
        {
            if (secs != DateTime.Now.Second)
            {
                secs = DateTime.Now.Second;
                using (Ping p = new Ping())
                {
                    int hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;
                    int mm = DateTime.Now.Minute;
                    int ss = DateTime.Now.Second;

                    string time = "";

                    if (hh < 10)
                    {
                        time += "0";
                        time += hh;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time += hh;
                    }
                    time += ":";

                    if (mm < 10)
                    {
                        time += "0";
                        time += mm;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time += mm;
                    }
                    time += ":";

                    if (ss < 10)
                    {
                        time += "0";
                        time += ss;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        time += ss;
                    }
                    string successString = ("Ping Successful - " +       p.Send(textBox2.Text).RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms    " + time + "\n");
                    Invoke((Action<string>)AddItemBox2,successString);
                }
            }
        }
        listBox2.Items.Add("\n");
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void AddItemBox2(string print)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(print);
        listBox2.Refresh();
        listBox2.TopIndex = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me.
Correct listbox?
keepgoing == false?
Backgroundworker started?

Comment: *facepalm* you nailed it, Backgroundworker not started, thanks!!